# Pythod xlrd Cell Type

Tags: python, types, cell

I have a spreadsheet, and the column I am processing is of DATE datatype.   However, I am using this code, and it returns type 1, which is TEXT.   It should return type 3, which is a DATE:

```
v_cell = v_worksheet.cell(i,int(v_date_col))
v_ctype = v_cell.ctype
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?   I formatted the column as a DATE in m/d/y h:m:s format.....

Thanks